# How do I go about calling a function that uses template T, into main function in order to print out the maximum value as a string?

Tags: c++

Okay so I created a template T that takes 3 parameters of type T, and asking the program to return the largest number. I have done so already; however, I would like for the result to return the answer as a string by calling findMax with 3 strings being "x", "y", and "z", in the main function. How can I go about doing so? I am a noob in C++, by the way.

```
template <class T>
T findMax(T a, T b, T c)
{
    int max = a;

    if (b > max)
    {
        max = b;
    }

    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
    }

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    cout << findMax(x, y, z) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... do you want to transform from strings to numbers and vice-versa? Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) combinations.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Other than missing a template <class T> declaration before your template function, the code you posted should do what you want.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why would you ever prefer '\n' over std::endl? Unless you want to be C-compatible, it doesn't really matter. I guess you get a change in performance, though as you are using streams to convert integers to strings, you have other optimizations to consider first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless really performance critical, don't write it yourself, use std::max instead. However as this is most likely for educational purposes, the importance is understanding it.

Whenever you have a template, try reading this code as if T was replaced by the wanted type. (Which is actually what the compiler does for you)

So, when called with std::string, you get the function:
`std::string findMax(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c)`

In which case, you will get a compilation error: `int max = a` as you can't assign a string to an integer. So either you need a conversion from std::string to int, which can be done by passing an std::function. However in this case, I guess you want to write `T max = a` or even `auto max = a`

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with single digit, positive integers, you can just change `int` to `char`, and it will work. For anything outside of [0-9], you will have to convert.

[stoi (string to int)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) will get you the numbers. Then on the way back out, use [to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) to return a string back.

Also, if you're expecting a certain input, you should not use a template. Your code would allow the caller to use a `string`, an `int`, and a `vector` which would just make everything go haywire when it actually ran.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool bigger_than(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return std::stoi(s1) > std::stoi(s2);
}

bool bigger_than(const int& i1, const int& i2)
{
    return i1 > i2;
}

template<class T>
const T& findMax(T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return bigger_than(a, b) ? a : b;
}

template<class T>
const T& findMax(T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return findMax(a, findMax(b, c));
}

/* --alternative for unlimited number of arguments

template<class T>
const T& findMax(T const& a)
{
    return a;
}

template<class T, class...Rest>
decltype(auto) findMax(T const& a, Rest const&... rest)
{
    return findMax(a, findMax(rest...));
}
*/

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    cout << findMax(x, y, z) << endl;

    auto xx = std::string("50");
    auto yy = std::string("30");
    auto zz = std::string("55");
    cout << findMax(xx, yy, zz) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
3
55
```